How to resize web-widget inside SwiftUI macOS app
I want to show web-widget
https://widget.cutwise.com/video/333
In my SwifUI app inside square area with my own size. 50x50 pt or 200x200pt… Any. Like that
Dream
My code is
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

let iframeHTML = """
<iframe
    name="Cutwise Player"
    width="480"
    height="480"
    frameborder="0"
    src="https://widget.cutwise.com/video/333"
    allowfullscreen
></iframe>
"""

struct WebView: NSViewRepresentable {
    let htmlContent: String

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return WKWebView()
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        nsView.loadHTMLString(htmlContent, baseURL: nil)
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        WebView(htmlContent: iframeHTML)
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    }
}

But I receive this
Reality
How can I squeeze an animated widget into the size I need?
